# Database access from different threads in Android

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have a Service that downloads data from the Internet in AsyncTasks. It parses the data and store it in a db. The Service runs continuously.

There is a change that a Activity attempts to read from the db while the Service is writing to it.

I have a database helper with several methods for writing and reading. Could this cause problems? Potentially trying to open the db from two different threads?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there has been talked and written many books about concurrency problems in db .

But using stackoverflow like a wikipedia i have found some interesting [thing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610147/android-sqlite-concurrency-without-exceptions):

> Sqlite on android lets you access the database from multiple procs for
>   reads, but if you're currently writing from one process, reads and
>   writes from other procs will throw an exception because the first
>   write has a lock on the db.

**Then the database is well protected from others threads** . **The bad news is that you must manage those exceptions** , and can be a dirty work if you have a big database (meaning with big many tables with much data exchange)

Comment: Thank you! It doesn't have to be a big problem I guess. If the Service owns a instance of the db-helper and the activity another. Then i just have to do try/catch in each method of the db-helper?!

Answer (score 2):

As long as you're only using one instance of a `SQLiteDatabase`, you should be fine.  Just make sure to only do your db read/write transactions within your database helper, and no other classes.  Any transactions made with the same database object will be synchronized for you automatically.