# Android Async Syncronization

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I have a `DBApdater` class that is accessed through many `AsyncTasks`. Each operation defined on the DB has to call a function written in the `DBAdappter` class called open, insert or delete from the db, and then close the DB. If one Async object has called open through an object of the `DbApater` how can i prevent a second `AsyncTasks` to call open until the first `AsyncTask` has called close on the DB. Could i use a lock like public `static Object myLock =new Object();`

and in the open mentod write

```
public void open()
{
      synchronizaed(myLock.getClass)
      {///Open the DB  
      }
}

public void close()
{
    synchronizaed(myLock.getClass)
      {///close the DB  
      }
     notify();
}
```

would this code work. Basically the calling class would obtain a lock on the open menthod and release it only when close is called.

Kind Regards,

Muhammad Mateen

Comment: Usually, you would synchronize on `myLock`, not `myLock.getClass()`. `notify()` is not required. And `myLock` should definitely not be `public`.

Comment: That code will just prevent concurrent calls to `open` and `close`. It will not prevent for example, `Thread1` opens the database, `Thread2` modifies the database, `Thread1` modifies the database, `Thread2` closes the database.

Comment: ContentProvider:s are your friends - not mortal enemies that must be defeated by littering your Activity classes with SQLiteDatabase object references.

Comment: Possible duplicate questions [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3610147/android-sqlite-concurrency-without-exceptions) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7654050/database-access-from-different-threads-in-android), see if those help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Synchronizing the access to database via `open()` and `close()` methods is the right approach in my mind. This should work.

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with the specifics of thread safe communication in an android development, but looking at your suggestion from a C# developers point of view it makes sense.