# Does ormLite callInTransaction lock the database?

Tags: java, android, ormlite

I was wondering if ormLite locked the database when it executed a transaction. I have table:

```
key | value
AA  | 1
BB  | 1
```

I have two database operations running. One modifies multiple entries:

```
new Callable<Void>() {
    public Void call() throws SQLException {
        pairAA = new DbEntry("AA", 2);
        pairBB = new DbEntry("BB", 2);
        dao.createOrUpdate(pairAA);
        dao.createOrUpdate(pairBB);

        return null;
    }
}
```

If I try to run the first on different thread, using `TransactionManager.callInTransaction()` is it possible to get 3 as a result of `sumAllValues(dao.queryAll())`? Running on different threads means the JVM may try to execute `queryAll()` between `createOrUpdate(pairAA)` and `createOrUpdate(pairBB)`. Which would mean AA becomes 2, BB is still 1 when the query reads it. Or would the transaction manager lock that table/database for the whole execution of the callable, making it impossible for the query to happen (only allowing it before or after the callable)?

Comment: a transaction is supposed to be atomical

Comment: It is not possible, a query made outside this transaction won't see the changes until transaction isn't commited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TransactionManager.callInTransaction()` turns off auto commit and commiting your changes after call() method executed or rollback them if call() method throws exception.

So it's not possible to get situation with `queryAll()` you described.
Also Android SQLite allow multiple readers but only one writer at a time details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7740305/2055854